# Return associated records where paperclip attachment exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, paperclip

My app lists corporate events and allows users to write reports on these events with an optional photo added via paperclip.

I want to return a list of associated reports that have an attachment.

My Event `has_many :reports`

My Reports `belongs_to :event` and:

`has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :thumb => "150x150#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)`

I am trying to return all associated reports that have attached photos in the event_controller "show" action by doing this:

`@hasphoto = @event.reports.where.not(:photo => nil)`

but i'm getting the following error:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'reports.photo' in 'where clause': SELECT 'reports'.* FROM 'reports' WHERE 'reports.event_id = 13 AND ('reports'.'photo' IS NOT NULL)

Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong or, if i'm approaching this task the wrong way, how I should be approaching it?

Comment: Try `@event.reports.photo?`

Answer (score 3):

Based on Paperclip's [`add_attachment`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/7edb35a2a9a80c9598dfde235c7e593c023fc914/lib/paperclip/schema.rb) sources, your code should look like:

```
@hasphoto = @event.reports.where.not(photo_file_name: nil)
```

Also, you have an option to run in console `rails db` (`rake db` for Rails 4-) and type:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE reports\G
```